# java code to remove extra forward slash

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to remove the forward slash at the end of the String which is repeating twice using Java.

Here is what I have:

```
String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com//";
length  =  s.length();
Char buff = s.charAt((length);
if(buff == '//')
{

}
else  LOGGER.info("Doesnt end with trailing doubleslash");
```

Please suggest how can i remove extra forward slash when i'm displaying the URL.Thanks.

Comment: looks like you want some regex to replace every // that is not in the URI protocol (e.g. http://)

Comment: [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) will never return two characters. (You also miscounted the parentheses on that line.)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the trailing double slash (`//`), whenever present, you can try something like

```
if (s.endsWith("//")
{
    s = s.substring(0, s.length()-2); // Remove the last 2 characters, i.e. the //
}
else
{
    LOGGER.info("Doesnt end with trailing doubleslash");
}
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question carefully -- no need for a regex!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to give the simplest possible answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Try using regex:](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

```
String s = "http://almaden.ibm.com//somethingElse//index.php";
s=s.replaceAll("//","/").replaceFirst(":/", "://"); 
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
http://almaden.ibm.com/somethingElse/site.html
```

Explanation:

```
s.replaceAll("//","/")
```

replaces all occurances of `//` to `/`, and then

```
.replaceFirst(":/", "://")
```

recreates double slashes `//` after the `protocol:` string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version would just check if it ends in `//` and if it does remove one character from the end

```
if(s.endsWith('//')) {
    s = s.substring(s.length()-1);
}
```

if it could be anywhere in the string then you can use a regular expression

```
s = s.replaceAll("(//)(?<!(\\w+\\://))", "/");
```

Comment: if it could be found anywhere, isnt this sufficient? s = s.replaceAll("//*", ""); When I tried this s = s.replaceAll("(//)(?<!(\\w+\\://))", "/"); if s contains // at the beginning then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that matches only a double slash at the end of the string:

```
s = s.replaceAll("//$", "/");
```

The dollar means "end of input". The rest is self explanatory.

---

If you wanted to be more flexible about it, you could:

```
s = s.replaceAll("//*\\s*$", "/");
```

which handles any number of trailing slashes and trims trailing whitespace too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://almaden.ibm.com//".replace(/\/\/$/,'/')
```

`/\/\/$/` matches a `//` at the end of the string